# how to use filter and map to alter object

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

how to modify the existing object by using map and filter.. below I have given two objects and needed output.

```
let a = [
  { a: "hi", b: 0 },
  { a: "bye", b: 1 },
  { a: "seeyou", b: 2 },
];
let b = { hi: "22:00", bye: "20:00", seeyou: "12:00" };
```

here I need like this response as below

```
c = [
  { a: "hi", b: 0, time: "22:00" },
  { a: "bye", b: 1, time: "20:00" },
  { a: "seeyou", b: 2, time: "12:00" },
];
```

how modify the object `a` to `c` using map and filter

Comment: `Array.prototype.map()` and `Array.prototype.filter()` both do **not** mutate the initial array in-place, so it is impossible to achieve what you are asking for. This is an [XY Problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: What have you tried? You already know that you have to use methods like `.map` or `.filter`. Please show your attempt.

Comment: @Quentin your idea to create a post/wiki about "I want to transform my very specific data format into this other very specific data format" sounds better every day

Comment: @PavanK The point of Stackoverflow is not "I have this input, I want this output, please give me the code." You are supposed to show what you've tried, so we can help you with it, not develop your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you just want to get an expected result?

If so, **example below**

```js
let a = [
  { a: "hi", b: 0 },
  { a: "bye", b: 1 },
  { a: "seeyou", b: 2 },
];
let b = { hi: "22:00", bye: "20:00", seeyou: "12:00" };

const output = a.map(el => ({
  ...el,
  time: b[el.a],
}));

console.log(output);
```

Comment: thank you... actullay i have updated my query.. could you please check it

Comment: @PavanK, you don't need to use filter() then. see my updated answer.